# Javascript shallow copies

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Javascript and ran into a problem with object references. Here's a snippet of the code that reproduces the issue.

```
function MyVector() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

function MySprite() {
    this.pos = new MyVector();
}

var my_sprite = new MySprite(); 
var my_pos = my_sprite.pos;    // my_pos points to my_sprite's vector
var my_vect = new MyVector();  // my_vector is on the heap
my_vect.x = 69;

print("my_pos.x: " + my_pos.x);  // prints 0 (expected)

my_sprite.pos = my_vect;         // should point to my_vect

print("my_sprite.pos.x: " + my_sprite.pos.x); // prints 69 (expected)
print("my_pos.x: " + my_pos.x);  // prints 0, expected to print 69
```

In the last print statement, I would've expected my_pos.x to print 69 since my_pos now refers to my_vect (or does it?). My understanding of Javascript is that only primitive values are actually copied and that object assignment maintains a reference to a single copy of the object. It looks like after the assignment of my_vect, the my_pos reference is somehow "detached" and no longer points to my_sprite.pos.

Is there some behavior of Javascript that I'm overlooking here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code with more comments, hope this helps

```
function MyVector() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

function MySprite() {
    this.pos = new MyVector();
}

var my_sprite = new MySprite();
```

at this point, a new MyVector() is created and assigned to my_sprite.pos. Let call it vector#1

```
var my_pos = my_sprite.pos;    // my_pos points to my_sprite's vector
```

my_pos points to vector#1 (you assign the pointer, not the data)

```
var my_vect = new MyVector();  // my_vector is on the heap
```

a new MyVector is created let's call it vector#2. Also, my_vect points to vector#2

```
my_vect.x = 69;

print("my_pos.x: " + my_pos.x);  // prints 0 (expected)

my_sprite.pos = my_vect;         // should point to my_vect
```

the pos member of my_sprite now points to vector#2

```
print("my_sprite.pos.x: " + my_sprite.pos.x); // prints 69 (expected)
```

but my_pos still points to vector#1 as it was never re-assigned!

```
print("my_pos.x: " + my_pos.x);  // prints 0, expected to print 69
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things up. Seems a lot more obvious once it's broken down.

Answer (score 0):

Your not overlooking anything.

```
var my_sprite = new MySprite();
```

so here,

```
my_sprite.pos == new myVector(); 
var my_pos = my_sprite.pos;  // my_pos equals that new myVector.
```

You never re-assign `my_pos`, so it still equals that new myVector when you print it.
When assigning variables in javascript, `my_pos` does not point to `my_sprite.pos` since `my_sprite.pos` is also a pointer, so it simple points to what `my_sprite.pos` points to.

Comment: I can't tell what in your answer is code and what is prose. It hurts to read.

Comment: Initially, I thought there was some dynamic lookup magic happening where my_pos actually references the vector that my_sprite.pos *currently* references. As Damp pointed out, that's not the case. It references the vector that my_sprite.pos pointed to at the time of my_pos's assignment. Basically, I was over-complicating the problem.